# Java List problems with Polymorphism

Tags: java, list, polymorphism

I want to write a textbased game in Java and have a Problem.
I got a `HeadArmor` Object that `extends Armor` that `extends Item` and this `implements IEquipable`.
If I add a `HeadArmor` Object to my `LinkedList` and try to access it, it becomes a `Item` Object.

```
private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
```

The method how I get the Object out of the List.

```
public Item getItemByName(String name) {            
    int i = 0;
    for (Item item : items) {
        if (item.getName().equals(name)) {
            //And the output is a Item Object and no HeadArmor
            System.out.println(items.get(i).getClass().getName());
            return items.get(i);
        }           
     i++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Therefore I can't check if my Object is a instance of `HeadArmor`.

```
public boolean equip(String name){
        Item item = getItemByName(name);
        //here he prints out I AM A DieWeltvonZuul.Item CLASS
        System.out.println("I AM A "+item.getClass().getName()+ " CLASS");

        if(item instanceof Weapon){
            if (null != weapon) {
                items.add(weapon);
                weapon = (Weapon) item;
            }else{
                weapon = (Weapon) item;
            }
        }else{
            //here he won't enter even the Object was at the beginning of type HeadArmor and this Object extends Armor
            if (item instanceof Armor){
                changeItem((IEquippable) getItemByName(name));
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If I try to cast it to a HeadArmor I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: DieWeltvonZuul.Item cannot be cast to DieWeltvonZuul.HeadArmor
```

Comment: There is a problem with logic.

Comment: Is there any non-obvious reason why you are using a separate index to access the item. You already got the correct item at hand in your for-each loop...

Comment: It would be much easier if you have posted [mcve]

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to create your items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `for (Item item : items)` is a good choice. Why would you then use `i`? It makes no sense.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but let me show you the following code:

```
public Item getItemByName(String name) { 
    for (Item item : items) {
        if (item.getName().equals(name)) {
            if (item instanceof HeadArmor) {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your `HeadArmor` added to the `List<Item>` doesn't become an `Item`. It is an `Item` already. Each `HeadArmor` is an `Item`, an `Armor` and `HeadArmor`. It's also an `Object`. However all objects in the `List<Item>` are guaranteed to be `Items` (and `Object`s) and nothing else. If you want to check if they are also `Armor` or `HeadArmor` you have to `try` to `cast`. If `cast`ing is successful, it means that this certain `item` was `instance of HeadArmor`.

I assume that what you want might be the following:

```
Item i = getItemByName("helmet");
Header h = ((i == null) ? null : (HeadArmor)i);
```

Comment: You should never use exception handling for control logic, it is a bad coding practice. Use `instanceof` instead.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin You're right. Edited.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin copying my answer recommendation?

Comment: @Cold Fire: I upvoted it :>

Comment: ok just was asking

Comment: I used the counter i just for a small test.    
If I try to cast my Item that is a HeadArmor i get a    
java.lang.ClassCastException that I cannot cast my Item to HeadArmor and to compare with instanceOf won't work too.

Comment: @BryanWTF, see my answer. Probably there is a problem with the way you create and add the items to the list.

Comment: @BryanWTF You're trying to cast a null probably. Try the last two lines as they are updated.

Comment: @BryanWTF are you sure that you don't modify the referenced content after adding to the list? It looks like you might have some duplicates on this list and miss some expected elements. Could you please `print(list.toString())`

Comment: the problem was that I castet somewhere my HeadArmor to Item... ^^"
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If I use this code to add items to the list

```
items.add(new HeadArmor("helmet"));
items.add(new Armor("chain mail"));
```

And try to retrieve `helmet` with your `getItemByName` method. The Output will be `HeadArmor` just as expected. Maybe there is an issue in the way you create and add the items to the item list?!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method `instanceOf` to check whether the item is of type `headArmor` or not